# Python 3: Construct a variable by parsing a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe with the columns `id`, `start`, `end`, `name`:

```
A   7   340 string1
B   12  113 string2
B   139 287 string3
B   301 348 string4
B   379 434 string5
C   41  73  string6
C   105 159 string7
```

and I am reading this into python3 using `pandas`:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("table", comment="#", header=None, names=["id", "start", "end", "name"])
```

Now I need to parse the `df` and extract for each `id` the `start`, `end` and `name` into a list of the following format:

```
mylist = [GraphicFeature(start=XXX, end=YYY, color="#ffffff", label="ZZZ")]
```

`XXX` here is the `start`, `YYY` is the `end`, `ZZZ` is the "name". The list has therefore as many items as number of rows per `id`.
`GraphicFeature` is just a member name of a module.

I thought of looping over the dataframe like this:

```
uniq_val = list(df["id"].unique())
for i in uniq_val:
    extracted = df.loc[df["id"] == i]
```

But how do I construct `mylist`? (There will be some other plotting commands after constructing the list).

My expected "output" in the loop therefore is:

for id `A`:

```
mylist = [GraphicFeature(start=7, end=340, color="#ffffff", label="string1")]
```

for id `B`:

```
mylist = [GraphicFeature(start=12, end=113, color="#ffffff", label="string2"), GraphicFeature(start=139, end=287, color="#ffffff", label="string3"), GraphicFeature(start=301, end=348, color="#ffffff", label="string4"), GraphicFeature(start=379, end=434, color="#ffffff", label="string5")]
```

for id `C`:

```
mylist = [GraphicFeature(start=41, end=73, color="#ffffff", label="string6"), GraphicFeature(start=105, end=159, color="#ffffff", label="string7")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to let

```
mylists = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda group: group.apply(lambda row: GraphicFeature(start=row['start'], end=row['end'], color='#ffffff', label=row['name']), axis=1).tolist())
```

Spelling this out a little bit, note that pandas operations tends to fit together most tidily if one takes a functional programming approach; we want to turn each row into a `GraphicFeature`, and in turn we want to turn each group of rows with the same `id` into a list of `GraphicFeature`. As such, the above could also be expanded to

```
def row_to_graphic_feature(row):
    return GraphicFeature(start=row['start'], end=row['end'], color='#ffffff', label=row['name'])

def id_group_to_list(group):
    return group.apply(row_to_graphic_feature, axis=1).tolist()

mylists = df.groupby('id').apply(id_group_to_list)
```

With your example data:

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
  id  start  end     name
0  A      7  340  string1
1  B     12  113  string2
2  B    139  287  string3
3  B    301  348  string4
4  B    379  434  string5
5  C     41   73  string6
6  C    105  159  string7

In [39]: mylists = df.groupby('id').apply(id_group_to_list)

In [40]: mylists['A']
Out[40]: [GraphicFeature(start=7, end=340, color='#ffffff', label='string1')]

In [41]: mylists['B']
Out[41]:
[GraphicFeature(start=12, end=113, color='#ffffff', label='string2'),
 GraphicFeature(start=139, end=287, color='#ffffff', label='string3'),
 GraphicFeature(start=301, end=348, color='#ffffff', label='string4'),
 GraphicFeature(start=379, end=434, color='#ffffff', label='string5')]

In [42]: mylists['C']
Out[42]:
[GraphicFeature(start=41, end=73, color='#ffffff', label='string6'),
 GraphicFeature(start=105, end=159, color='#ffffff', label='string7')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop

```
l=[[GraphicFeature(start=x[0], end=x[1], color="#ffffff", label=x[2])for x in zip(y.start,y.end,y.name) ] for _,y in df.groupby('id')]
```

Comment: This is writing a variable for each line, not for each unique `id`.

Comment: And what is `axis=1` in the initializer for `GraphicFeature`? That doesn't appear to be part of their data structure.

Comment: @Wen-Ben: No worries; I think the downvote is because the first version of the answer was rather broken.

Comment: @fuglede let me help you back :-)